# What keys does regsvr32.exe add for a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, dllregistration

I'm not sure if this is a simple question or it varies depending on the DLL... I have a codebase where the DLL uses atlbase.h and I *think* that means it registers a fairly standard set of keys/values? If so, is there a guide on MSDN how do write a script to install (and more importantly uninstall) the same keys so my installer can do the same thing?

Comment: You can be just as sure of `regsvr32.exe`'s existence as you are of the `Registry`s existence - typically you just call out to `regsvr32.exe`.

Comment: I've been told this is a bad way to do things though I don't exactly know why.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204770%28VS.85%29.aspx#no_selfreg

Answer (score 1):

ATL by itself adds nothing. Usually an ATL project has a number of co-creatable classes, and each class has a [registry script](http://www.google.com/search?q=atl+registry+scripting) associated with it. regsrv32 simply calls DllRegisterServer. ATLs implementation of DllRegisterServer loops through the list of co-creatable classes and calls processing of each registry script. So, registry is written with the information provided in registry scrips. By default, that is standard COM classes and interfaces metadata. It can be something else, provided that a developer put some extra information in the registry script.